# spring boot interface extends multiple interfaces

Tags: java, spring, interface

I have an interface A and a class AImpl that implements it.

```
public interface A {a()}
 @Component
class AImpl implements A{...}
```

and I have an interface B and a class BImpl that implements it.

```
 public interface B {b()}
 @Component
class BImpl implements B{...}
```

A and B have different methods

```
interface C extends A, B {...}
```

is there a way to Autowired C c; without putting any qualifier and call

```
c.a();
```

Comment: It depends on how many implementations you have for interface `C`. Is it only one or multiple?

Comment: I don't have any implementation of C , actually I wanted that C will encapsulate all of the methods , without the need to reimplement a and b and call A.a and B.b

Comment: But C is just an Interface. You can't have a Spring-managed bean of an Interface if you provide no implementation for it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you don't need any qualifier to autowire a bean of type C. Just do:

```
@Component
class CImpl implements C {...}

@Service
class OtherService {
  
  @Autowired
  C c;

}
```

Comment: Right, presuming there is precisely 1 implementation of C registered as a bean

Comment: thanks for your response, actually I don't want to implement C

Comment: @meriemB That doesn't make sense. Where is the implementation of `c.a()` coming from if you never write it?

Comment: Then there's no case. You need at least 1 implementation class.

Comment: c.a() will call the default method A.a()